# How to put cursor into the start of edittext instead of middle of the whole edittext?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have EditText which takes up the entire screen. And cursor is always in the middle of EditText, but I need it to be at the top of EditText. What am I supposed to do?
My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textImeMultiLine|textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `android:gravity="start|top"` & `android:textAlignment="viewStart"`

Here' the full code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textImeMultiLine|textMultiLine"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your EditText.

```
android:gravity="top|left"
```